# Applying a function to the value in foreach before entering the loop

Tags: php

I think this is simply not possible but hopefully I can be proven wrong.

I would like to achieve one of the "`does not work`" lines from below:

```
<?php
// Note, this is purposely an overly simplistic example

// Pretend that I do not control this array and it is
// provided to me from the database or an API or something
$data_array = [
    ' a ',
    ' b ',
    ' c '
];

$new_array = [];

// Apply a function call before entering the loop
// foreach( $array as trim( $v ) ) // does not work
// foreach( $array as $v = trim( $v ) ) // does not work
foreach( $data_array as $v ) // works but I don't want this
{
    $v = trim( $v ); // works but I don't want this
    $new_array[ $v ] = $v;
}

var_dump( $new_array );
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(1) "a"
  ["b"]=>
  string(1) "b"
  ["c"]=>
  string(1) "c"
}
```

Comment: you are searching for `foreach($items as $key => $value`), your line is `$array|$key] = $v`

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant I appreciate your time but please re-read the question. I would like to apply `trim()` to `$v` before going into the loop. Thanks.

Comment: `foreach(array_map(function($v) { return trim($v); }, explode(',', $str)) as $v)`

Comment: Or shorter: `foreach(array_map(explode(',', $str), 'trim') as $v) `

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why you say 'works but I don't want this' - 1 line of code - how is it affecting what your doing?

Comment: @NigelRen I want to apply a function call before entering the loop. In my code I am showing how it is traditionally achieved and the two "`does not work`" lines are examples of what I am imagining.

Comment: What difference does it make if you apply it before entering the loop or in the first line of the loop?

Comment: @NigelRen ["Syntactic sugar"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple and works with functions that take only one argument:

```
foreach(array_map('trim', $array) as $v) {
    $array[$v] = $v;
}
```

However, to achieve the new string keys without the integer keys, you need to `unset` it:

```
foreach(array_map('trim', $array) as $k => $v) {
    unset($array[$k]);
    $array[$v] = $v;
}
```

An alternate to the loop:

```
$array = array_combine($v = array_map('trim', $array), $v);
```

To actually modify the value by reference you need to reassign the array:

```
foreach($array = array_map('trim', $array) as &$v) {
    $v = $v.' woo!';
}
```

All that being said, you have already shown the most efficient and probably most readable way to achieve your results:

```
foreach($array as $v) {
    $v = trim($v);
    $array[$v] = $v;
}
```

Comment: This is probably the closest to what I am imagining but unfortunately wouldn't work right if `as &$v` was used and modified in the loop. The assigning of the keys is not important but thanks for the second two examples.

Comment: If you can give an example using `as &$v` and how it doesn't work I can check.

Comment: This solution goes through the array twice. array_map is a loop. It achieves syntactic sugar at the expense of efficiency.

Comment: @AbraCadaver `foreach(array_map('trim', $array) as &$v){ $v = $v.' woo!'; }` leaves `$array`'s values unchanged.

Comment: @ryantxr:  Yes, they already know the efficient way but seem to be looking for another.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: Edited, however I would stick with what you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = " a , b , c ";
$array = [];

// note the space around commas, 
// you can explode by that string instead of trim
foreach(explode(' , ', $str) as $v) {
    $array[$v] = $v;
}

var_dump($array);
```

You can also do an `str_replace` before going to the for loop to remove whitespaces, if there is multiple:

```
$str = str_replace(' ', '', $str);
foreach(explode(',', $str) as $v) {
    // ...
```

This won't work for the following type of strings though:

```
$str = "a a , b , c";
// str_replace will result in
// "aa,b,c"
```

---

**EDIT:** Now that you have updated your question:

```
$array = [
    ' a ',
    ' b ',
    ' c '
];

$array  = array_map('trim', $array);
$result = array_combine($array, $array);

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Pretend that I don't control how the array is built. See my updated question.